# In tkinter, it showed "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def kiir2():
    if sz1.get()%2==0:
        prs1=Label(ablak,text=sz1.get())
        prs1.grid(row=4,column=2)
    elif sz3.get()%2==0:
        prs2=Label(ablak,text=sz3.get())
        prs2.grid(row=4,column=2)
    elif sz5.get()%2==0:
        prs3=Label(ablak,text=sz5.get())
        prs3.grid(row=4,column=2)
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`.get()` returns a string. `%2` is trying to do string formatting, not a modulo operation. If you're trying to do a modulo operation, you need to convert the value to an int.

```
if int(sz1.get())%2 == 0:
   ...
```

A better practice, however, is to do the conversion and the math in separate steps, since the conversion could throw errors due to bad data (user not entering anything, the user entering a non-integer, etc).

```
try:
    sz1_value = int(sz1.get())
Except ValueError:
    <code to handle bad user input>
...
if sz1_value % 2 == 0:
    ...
```

Comment: It writes - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @BálintEmber: and that means that you're trying to convert an empty string. You have to call `int()` to convert it to an integer, but you need to wait until the user has entered something, and you need to check that what they entered is a valid number. The specific problem you asked about, however, is due to trying to do math on a string, which this answer addresses.